# Performing assertions on multiple properties of a Class

Tags: fluent-assertions

I know from the docs I can do this ...

```
result.Should().BeOfType<MyClass>().Which.Property1.Should().Be("String")
```

Is there a way I can test multiple properties, in a way similar

```
result.Should().BeOfType<MyClass>().Which.Property1.Should().Be("String").And.Property2.Should().Be(99);
```

It's also be good if it were possible to do either of the above tests without having to assert hat they are 'OfType' but I suspect that there is no other way for the code to know what properties are available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a structural comparison assertion against an anonymous type, like this:

`result.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(new 
{
   Property1 = "String",
   Property2 = 99
}, options => options.ExcludingMissingMembers());`

Comment: Nice one. Am liking this more and more.

Comment: Though it is nice, the problem I see with this solution that it is not strongly typed.

Comment: You can chain it with `result.Should().BeOfType<MyClass>().And.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(....`

Answer (score 2):

One simple solution is to use the AndWhichConstraint type returned by BeOfType<>().

This is what I end up doing:

```
var myClassType = result.Should().BeOfType<MyClass>;
myClassType.Which.Property1.Should().Be("String");
myClassType.Which.Property2.Should().Be(99);
```